# Машина Тьюринга через двусвязные списки СИ

Tags: c, list

Лента считывается из файла, оттуда же считывается и сама программа для МТ.
Суть программы МТ заключается в том, чтобы перевести 0 в 1 и наоборот. Со своей задачей справляется, но в конце сообщает об ошибке [image: Ошибка]

Происходит выполнение преобразования, но вместо записи в файл выдает указанную ошибку.

Прошу обратить внимание на один интересный факт. Если ввести ленту: 00110011, то все работает замечательно. Но если ввести сначала 1, а потом 0, к примеру 11010, то происходит аварийное завершение с указанной ошибкой.
Вот сам код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define MAXCOMMAND 256
typedef struct _progr {
    char inputsymb; //Входной символ
    int state; //Начальное состояние
    char outputsymb; //Символ на выходе
    int newstate; //Новое состояние
    char action; //Действие
} progr;
/*----------------------------------Список----------------------------------*/
/*Структура узел*/
typedef struct _Raw {
    char value; /*Хранит значение*/
    struct _Raw *next; /*Следующий элемент*/
    struct _Raw *prev; /*Предыдущий элемент*/
} Raw;
typedef struct _DbLink {
    size_t size; /*Хранит размер списка*/
    Raw *head; /*Начало списка*/
    Raw *tail; /*Конец списка*/
} DbLink;
/*Инициализация списка*/
DbLink* createDbLink() {
    DbLink *tmp;
    tmp = (DbLink*)malloc(sizeof(DbLink)); //Динамическое выделение памяти
    tmp->size = 0; //Обнуление размера списка
    tmp->head = tmp->tail = NULL;
    return tmp;
}
/*Функция удаления списка*/
void deleteDbLink(DbLink *list) {
    Raw *tmp = list->head;
    Raw *next = NULL;
    while (tmp) {
        next = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = next;
    }
    free(list);
}
/*Функция добавления в конец списка (т.к. если добавлять в начало, вся лента будет в обратной последовательности*/
void pushBack(DbLink *list, void *value) {
    Raw *tmp = (Raw*)malloc(sizeof(Raw));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        exit;
    }
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    tmp->prev = list->tail;
    if (list->tail) {
        list->tail->next = tmp;
    }
    list->tail = tmp;

    if (list->head == NULL) {
        list->head = tmp;
    }
    list->size++;
}

/*Функция распечатывания списка*/
void printfDbLink(DbLink *list) {
    Raw *tmp;
    tmp = list->head;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        printf("%c ", tmp->value);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
/*Операция над лентой(алфавитом)*/
void turing(DbLink *list, struct _progr arr[], int cmd) {
    int error = 0; //Переменная останова
    int headstate = 1; //Состояние головки
    char replace_symb; //Переменная для внесения нового значения
    FILE *result = fopen("result.txt", "wb");
    int i = 0; //Переменные для счетчика
    Raw *buff, *tmp; //Две переменные ссылающиеся на структуру _Raw
    tmp = list->head; //Присвоение переменной ссылки на Head в списке list
    fprintf(result, "Result is: ");
    while (tmp != NULL && error != 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < cmd; i++) {
        buff = tmp->value; //Присвоение переменной - значения лежащей в Head списка list
            if (buff == arr[i].inputsymb && headstate == arr[i].state) {
                replace_symb = arr[i].outputsymb;
                headstate = arr[i].newstate;
                fprintf(result, "%c", replace_symb);
                printf("%c ", replace_symb);
                switch (arr[i].action) {
                case 'R': { tmp = tmp->next; break;} //При команде R сдвигается на следующий элемент в списке
                case 'L': { tmp = tmp->prev; break;} //При команде L сдвигается на предыдущий элемент в списке
                case 'S': { error = 1; break;}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
/*---------------------------------main------------------------------------*/
int main(void) {
    DbLink *list = createDbLink(); //Инициализация списка
    int headstate = 1, bool = 1, len = 0, c = 0, i = 0, b = 0;
    long size = 0;
    char sep[] = ":,";
    char line[100];
    char *token;
    char *buf; //Массив для хранения алфавита считываемого из файла
    progr arr[MAXCOMMAND]; //Массив стуктуры для записи программы МТ
    FILE *fp = fopen("lenta.txt", "r"); //Открытие файла
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); //Проход до конца файла
    size = ftell(fp); //Узнаем размер файла в байтах
    buf = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char)); //Динамическое выделение памяти под массив хранения ленты
    rewind(fp); //Возвращение к началу файла
    while (!feof(fp)) { //До тех пор пока не будет достигнут конец файла
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &buf[i]); //По одному символу будет записыватся в массив
        i++; //Переход на следующий элемент массива
    }
    c = i - 1; ///Без этого печатает лишний пустой символ (????????)
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        pushBack(list, buf[i]);
    }
    /*---------------Извлечение программы МТ из файла!----------------------*/
    FILE *prog = fopen("prog.txt", "r");
    i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 100, prog) != NULL) {
        if (bool == 1) {
            len = strlen(line);
            for (i = 0;i<len;i++) {
                if (line[i] != '\r' && line[i] != '\n') {
                }
                else {
                    bool = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            headstate = 1;
            token = strtok(line, sep);
            while (token != NULL) {
                char symb;
                if (strlen(token) == 1) {
                    symb = *token;
                }
                else {
                    if (sscanf(token, "%c%cq%d", &(arr[i].outputsymb), &(arr[i].action), &(arr[i].newstate)) >= 0) {
                        arr[i].inputsymb = symb;
                        arr[i].state = headstate++;

                        printf("%cq%d-%cq%d%c\n", arr[i].inputsymb, arr[i].state, arr[i].outputsymb, arr[i].newstate, arr[i].action);
                        i++;
                    }
                }

                token = strtok(NULL, sep);
            }
        }
    }
    /*------------------Окончание считывания!--------------------*/
    printfDbLink(list);
    printf("DBLink length %d\n", list->size);
    turing(list, arr, i);
    deleteDbLink(list);
    system("pause");
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

**Update.**

Исправил сравнение, теперь

```
char temp = tmp->value; 
temp == arr[i].inputsymbol
tmp->value = value
```

(char* value теперь)

Все такая же ошибка[image: sameerror]

**-----Update-----**

Исправил ошибку, проблема действительно была в работе с памятью. Я пытался взять значение из NULL. Добавил еще одну проверку `if (tmp != NULL)`
В общем вот, спасибо всем за помощь!

```
void turing(DbLink *list, struct _progr arr[], int cmd) {
    int error = 0; //Переменная останова
    int headstate = 1; //Состояние головки
    char replace_symb; //Переменная для внесения нового значения
    char temp; //Переменная для записи значения из head->value
    FILE *result = fopen("result.txt", "wb");
    int i = 0; //Переменные для счетчика
    Raw *tmp; //Переменная ссылающаяся на структуру _Raw
    tmp = list->head; //Присвоение переменной ссылки на Head в списке list
    fprintf(result, "Result is: ");
    while (tmp != NULL && error != 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < cmd; i++) {
            if (tmp != NULL) {
                temp = tmp->value; //Присвоение переменной - значения лежащей в Head списка list
                if (temp == arr[i].inputsymb && headstate == arr[i].state) {
                    replace_symb = arr[i].outputsymb;
                    headstate = arr[i].newstate;
                    fprintf(result, "%c", replace_symb);
                    printf("%c ", replace_symb);
                    switch (arr[i].action) {
                    case 'R': { tmp = tmp->next; break;} //При команде R сдвигается на следующий элемент в списке
                    case 'L': { tmp = tmp->prev; break;} //При команде L сдвигается на предыдущий элемент в списке
                    case 'S': { error = 1; break;}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не закапывался глубоко. Так что просто ткну в очевидные вещи.

```
tmp->value = value;
```

Переменной типа `char` присваивается значение типа `void*`.

```
buff = tmp->value;
```

То же самое, но в обратную сторону.

```
buff == arr[i].inputsymb
```

Сравнение указателя и `char`.

```
pushBack(list, buf[i])
```

Я вообще не пойму - вы что, предупреждения компилятора отключили или игнорируете, не вникая? Компилятор их сразу выбрасывает десяток. Понимаете, разбираться, почему программа не работает, при таком исходнике - дело неблагодарное...

**Update**

Вот еще -

```
while (!feof(fp)) { //До тех пор пока не будет достигнут конец файла
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &buf[i]); //По одному символу будет записыватся в массив
        i++; //Переход на следующий элемент массива
    }
    c = i - 1; ///Без этого печатает лишний пустой символ (????????)
```

Обнаружение конца файла происходит при попытке чтения, вот откуда у вас лишний символ. Да и вообще - зачем вы читает так, если заранее выяснили размер? Просто

```
fread(buf,1,size,fp);
```

- и никаких циклов :)

Еще я бы крайне не рекомендовал использовать `bool` в качестве имени переменной...

Comment: пока наливал кофе,  уже ответили )))

Comment: Исправил ошибки, ничего не изменилось, та же проблема, та же ошибка!

Comment: Ну, я и не говорил, что причина в этом. Скорее всего она в каком-то неверном освобождении памяти, выходе за границу массива и т.п. Как минимум у вас есть два считываемых файла - lenta.txt и progs.txt - надо их иметь, чтоб получить конкретный воспроизводимый пример. Я о машине Тьюринга, например, знаю только то, что есть такое название - так что разбираться в том, что код делает, не буду точно. Но если будет воспроизводимый пример, то попытаюсь найти, что именно приводит к этой ошибке, не более того. Только вот этого примера у вас и нет...

Comment: lenta.txt 1000000
prog.txt

01
0:1Rq2,1Rq2 
1:0Rq2,0Rq2

Вот)

Answer (score 1):

Как это у Вас работает интересно.
в строке

```
  buff = tmp->value; //Присвоение переменной - значения лежащей в Head списка list
```

Вы присваиваете `char` указателю на структуру `Raw`

Comment: Исправил, так же не работает